# Artisan command notification to all users gives BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

How can I create an artisan command to send a database notification to all users in the system containing information of how long they have been in the system for?

My SendEmails Command looks like the following:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\UserEmails;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

class SendEmails extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'send:emails';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send Email to allusers';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        foreach($users as $user){
            $created_at = $user->created_at;
            Notification::send($user, new SendEmailsNotification($created_at));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created the notifications table, migrated and the code is the below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class SendEmailsNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $created_at;

    public function __construct($created_at)
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }
}
```

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
//use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    //use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'image'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        //'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'address' => 'array'
    ];

    protected $uploads = '/images/';

    public function getImageAttribute($image){
        return $this->uploads . $image;
    }

    public function contacts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contact');
    }
}
```

When I run the artisan command "php artisan send:emails" I see the following error in the console:

> BadMethodCallException  : Call to undefined method App\User::routeNotificationFor()

How can I send the notification to all users?

Comment: @Rwd I just edited my question

Comment: Sorry but can you show the whole class i.e. what classes are being importing and what traits it's using.

Comment: @Rwd I just edited my question

Comment: Is there a reason you're passing the `created_at` to  each notification?

Comment: yes @Rwd. Because the content of the notification need to specify how the user has been a member for, in human-readable time

Comment: I understand that but the `User` is passed to all of the relevant methods in the notification class as `$notifiable` anyway so you can just access the date like `$notifiable->created_at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to uncomment the `// use Notifiable` line.

The `Notifiable` trait includes two other traits, one of which is the `RoutesNotifications` trait.

The `RoutesNotifications` trait is what you need to be able to send Notifications to a `User`.

---

Also, you should be able to simplify your code in your `SendEmails` command to be:

```
Notification::send(User::all(), new SendEmailsNotification());
```

And instead of explicitly passing `created_at` you can just access it from `$notifiable` in your `SendEmailsNotification` (as in this case `$notifiable` will be the `User` model anyway) e.g.

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'data' => 'Account Created' . $notifiable->created_at->diffForHumans()
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: I uncommented the the Notifiable line and the notification is sent, but I get an error in the toArray method because I have 'data' => 'Account Created' . $this->created_at->getDiffForHumans()
It says that getDiffForHumans() method does not exist

Comment: @deSousa Please can you updated the code in your question to show the code you currently have for your `SendEmailsNotification` class as currently the code you've provided is just returning an empty array.

Comment: @deSousa I have updated my answer to show how you can access the information.

Comment: I just noticed that it's actually diffForHumans() without the get. Hope you can update your answer.

Comment: @deSousa Updated. I don't know why I didn't see that myself haha. Glad I could help!

Comment: not a problem. I had accepted anyway because I actually answered the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to uncomment `use Notifiable;` as suggested in the other answer. Now `Notification::send()` is used to send the notification to multiple users and it expects the first argument to be a collection of notifiables (i.e. users), not an object. To send notifications individually in a loop, you should be doing something like this:

```php
foreach($users as $user) {
    $created_at = $user->created_at;
    $user->notify(new SendEmailsNotification($created_at));
}
```

But as the notifiable is already available in your notification, a better solution would be like this:

Your notification class:

```php
use Queueable;

public $created_at;

public function __construct()
{
    
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['database'];
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $created_at = $notifiable->created_at;
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    $created_at = $notifiable->created_at;
    return [
    ];
}
```

And in your Artisan command:

```php
$users = User::all();
Notification::send($users, new SendEmailsNotification());
```

Comment: You don't have to pass a collection of notifiables to `send`. If a single instance is passed through then it will wrap that instance for you.

Comment: @Rwd Thank you for the clarification. Documentation didn't mention that. That's why I assumed that it expects a collection always.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to let you know :)